# EntityFramework dependency injection of DatabaseContext on Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

i have not much knowledge about Asp and Entity Framework so i really cant figure out what i have to do.
My problem is accessing database context out of main asp method -
There is how db context created and used in Program.cs (Main)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDataSource"))
);

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

so my problem is kinda that i making "options" for DatabaseContext constructor out of "builder.Configuration"

But what do i do when i need to acces db from other script? DatabaseContext requires config but i just dont know how to get it outside of that builder.
one guy suggested me to use Dependency Injection, i have looked but i just cant get how to do it properly, like i make a class where i initialize db context, but i still need to somehow make a  config here and i really have no clue how.
It could be really stupid question but i really cant figure it out for a couple of days :D

I`ve tried to make DbContext without a config but it gives error

Comment: There are tutorials for using Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core. Did you look any of them up? Try to follow any of them? You haven't even shown the class where you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you tried, but I think this might be what you want.

Assuming your `DatabaseContext` class is the most basic, and defines a table
`Users` in it:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Models.User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then you register it in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDataSource"))
);
```

You can generate your database by migrating and updating the database(Of course you can also manually create):

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Then you can access your database in other classes through dependency injection, such as in the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _databaseContext;
    public HomeController(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
    {
        _databaseContext = databaseContext;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = _databaseContext.Users.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

For more details about dependency injection, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: So my problem was more on knowledge level, so i just didn't understood DI concept properly, but i`ve spent a couple of hours and now figured all out. But anyway thanks!